# Best JavaScript library for animating multiple divs

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a grid of div boxes that I will be animating. They will be moving across the screen after a user drags one of the boxes (to re-align into a grid).

Currently I am using JQuery to change the css left and top positions of all of the divs and running this on an interval.

It is laggy if there are more than 50 boxes. How do I make this less laggy? Is there an animation library that is better for this, or do I just need to limit it to 50 boxes?

Image of layout:
 [image]

Comment: Since JavaScript is a client side language the lag will be based off of the users machine (from what I understand).  I don't know that there will be a way to limit this for everyone.  The only thing that I could think to solve this is speed up the animation and animate one at a time... So once one if finished moving to the left/right the next in line follows suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options to optimize the performance.

1. Newer browsers have `requestAnimationFrame` that lets the browser take care of the animation timing in order to optimize Javascript animations. Rather than using times to perform the animation, which is what jQuery framework uses, you repeatedly a callback to requestAnimationFrame. The browser will call your function with a progress variable for the animation, and you render the current stage of your animation based on the progress variable. [requestAnimationFrame for smarting animating](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) talks about this in depth. Google Closure is the only framework I am aware of that uses requestAnimationFrame however, and it's rather heavyweight.
2. CSS animations. jQuery offers CSS animation, so do many other frameworks. CSS animations give you hardware acceleration, so the animation is much faster. Unfortunately, CSS animations are relatively new and not yet well supported, so you'll probably end up falling back to Javascript animation on older browsers, depending on the library you use.
3. Optimize your Javascript. Instead of animation each and every box in the grid, encapsulate each row in a div and animate the entire div instead. That should speed the animation up by a bit. I'm sure there are other ways you can optimize based on your current implementation.

Comment: I ended up going with your approach of using requestAnimationFrame and hardware accelerated CSS animations. The performance is much faster. @Charlie Rudenstål: I really loved your answer as well. I will try to implement UI virtualization in the future. If only I could select two answers.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't know of any library that will make this work more efficiently for you, though there are many libraries out there that are faster than jQuery. The issue isn't just the jQuery, its the fact that you have 50 elements that are all moving/draggable, thus requiring a lot of the browser's resources.

If you can post your code there may be a few things that we could suggest to speed it up slightly.

The two biggest things problems that I can think of are if you added those boxes programmatically and added the handler for each as you added the element to the page, and if you don't store your selectors in variables. Aside from that I would have to see the code.

Comment: var onDrag = function() { //code };
$("div.container").on('mousedown', "div.shape", onDrag);

That is how I bind the events. The div is not draggable until they click the box, and after they mouseup it destroys the draggable feature. This means there is only one draggable div at a time.

This is what is set on an interval: http://pastebin.com/NcHpukfY

The interval is only running when they are un-aligned, so that does not waste CPU by running when it isn't needed.

Comment: any interval will slow down processing significantly. can you show me the code including the setting and clearing of the interval, along with the handlers that call them?

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing the code, but I think the first step to improve the efficiency might be to eliminate the need for setInterval entirely and to attempt to use callbacks or a promise() instead

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of increasing the performance. One would be to reduce the amount of DOM elements required for each box. Another is to not animate (and render) boxes outside of the current viewport. Give all boxes that are outside of the viewable area "display: none;" and exclude them before starting a new animation. If you want to go even further you can start to recycle boxes instead of showing and hiding them when the user is scrolling through the page.

This way you will always get the same performance no matter how many boxes you have (above the amount that you can fit in the viewport).

This technique is called UI virtualization. There are several projects that use it like: http://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki. It's really useful when you need to render a lot of elements (hundreds, thousands, millions). But it takes quite some work to get it right. And I don't know about any generic working components that are easy to plug in. I tried to find an article that explains it. This is the only thing I could come up with for now, it's for Silverlight though: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Virtualization-in-Silverlight-4-RC.aspx

Also try this this plugin for jQuery. Use the regular 'animate' method and it will try to use (hardware accelerated) CSS animations where possible: http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/

Comment: How would I make the boxes outside of the viewable area be "display: none"? Also, if the user scrolls down, how would I be sure they are in the correct order?

Comment: Expanded my answer with what was previously a reply to your question above

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

[jQuery isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

It has options to allow you to use css3 animations if available or use jQuery / JS animations.

Handy for grid like animation and arrangements.

Some brave soul has managed to add drag and drop to isotope too. http://tyler-designs.com/masonry-ui/ (a bit clunky but works)

Comment: Mind, though, Isotope does not support dragging.

Comment: @Systembolaget: Someone has attempted to add drag and drop to isotope. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it's what David DeSandro wrote about in his blog about Tyler Boyd's brave attempt http://metafizzy.co/blog/mythical-drag-drop-multi-column-grid-plugin/ but it does not really work and is counter intuitive. The snag is: If one wants sorting - why need dragging? If one wants just animated boxes - why not just use CSS transfomations or the Canvas with HTML5? Dragging should be used where it makes sense - to self-sort, for example. Then again - why self-sort some boxes on a website?